# click on svg path to select html checkbox?

Tags: html, svg, checkbox

I've got a relatively complex svg depicting a cell embedded into my html page via an  tag. If you hover over certain paths of the svg (e.g. the nucleus), I've already managed to get them to change colour, and I've added a tooltip which shows a tiny window with a bit of text. So far so good.

I've also got a bunch of simple html checkboxes which are related to the svg (i.e. they are labelled 'nucleus' etc). All clicking on these checkboxes does is to set their value to 1.

Now, what I really want to achieve is to be able to click on a svg path (e.g. nucleus) which then

1. changes the color of the path - this I've managed to do with a simple function:

   ```
   function buttonClick(evt){
       document.getElementById("nucleus").style["fill"] = "yellow"; 
   }
   ```

   and then a

   ```
   onmouseup="buttonClick(evt)"
   ```

   in the corresponding path.
2. selects the corresponding checkbox. (My supervisor likes to be on the safe side and is all about browser compatibility so he wants the plain checkboxes as a backup, so unfortunately I can't just hide them behind the svg or something like that...)
3. On second click, everything needs to be reversed/unselected

Now, is that possible?

All I could find was: 
- how to replace a checkbox by an entire image (not what I need, just a svg path) OR 
- how to make style checkboxes in svg/css. (Nice, but also not what I need)  OR
- how to select a checkbox in jquery. I've tried this

```
$('.comp_nuc')[0].checked = true;
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
myCheckbox:<input onClick=myCheckChecked() id=myCheckbox type="checkbox" />
<svg width=400 height=400>
<circle id="myCircle" onClick=circleClicked() cx=200 cy=200 fill=red r=100 />
</svg>
<script>
function circleClicked()
{
    if( myCircle.getAttribute("fill")=="red")
    {
        myCircle.setAttribute("fill","yellow")
        myCheckbox.checked=true
    }
    else
    {
        myCircle.setAttribute("fill","red")
        myCheckbox.checked=false
    }

}
function myCheckChecked()
{
    if(myCheckbox.checked==true)
        myCircle.setAttribute("fill","yellow")
    else
        myCircle.setAttribute("fill","red")
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, guys, this works well if I have the svg code written in my html file. I'd like to have the whole thing embedded, though (It's an extra 900 lines of code I don't really want in my html file...) Is that possible somehow? I was unable to get it done. The color change is fine, but the checkbox doesn't work when the svg is not written into the html file.

Comment: @DaReHo Are you calling an svg file into the HTML page via XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: @Francis no, I just had an object tag. I think this info got lost in the edit. Now I've just copied the whole svg code where the object tag used to be and it works. I'd prefer a object tag, though, as I've read on bunch of forums that it offers a great deal of flexibility. And just makes the whole script a bit cleaner. I'll have a look into xmlhttprequest now, Thanks!!